# 'Go to list' link for related list when just a few related list records

Tags: related-list

When you look at a related list on a SFDC page, and there are more than 5 records, you get a link that says 'Go to List'.  Is there a way for that link to be ALWAYS present, even if there are fewer than 5?  I'm talking about out of box functionality, not customization.

Thx,
Hamayoun

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box solution. All solutions for this particular request would involve at minimum customization, and probably at least a couple of lines of code, too.